# What are the uses of default function template arguments

Tags: c++11, function-templates

Unlike the *class* template arguments, which have to be specified by the user of the template, the *function* template arguments are deduced by the compiler. Therefore, a natural question arises: why might one want to specify *default* function template arguments?

One usage I can come up with is when we want to force some of the function template arguments without needing to specify all of them. However, this seems to be a corner case. Are there other cases?

Comment: "function template arguments are deduced by the compiler". [Or not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Comment: I was in the middle of writing the reply when this was posted :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a partial answer. One use I thought of is when we have a template parameter that does not appear as type in the function's parameter list and thus cannot be deduced. Providing a default argument for that template parameter might be very reasonable. The above comment by n.m. provides a good example of this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert below  `func` into the `constructor`( they dont have return type).

```
  template<class T>
  typename std::enable_if< std::is_fundamental<T>::value >::type func(T p_arg){}

  template<class T>
  typename std::enable_if< !std::is_fundamental<T>::value >::type func(T const &p_arg){}
```

Its pretty easy with default function template arguments.

Comment: It is not so clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Could you please help me by following up on the last sentence with code?

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
 template <typename Y, typename Y, int Z>
 class Do{};
```

X,Y,Z are template parameters.

A user can use this like:

```
 Do<int,int,1> doit;
```

While using a class template there is no way that template parameters get deduced from a function argument.

You call something "default" arguments...

```
 template <typename Y, typename Y, int Z=9>
 class Do{};
```

Here Z is defaulted to 9 if nothing was given from the using code like:

```
Do<int,int> doit;
```

And if your template arguments can be deduced from function arguments a user maybe want a special template instance to be used like:

```
template <typename T>
void func( const T&);

    template<>
void func( const int& )
{   
    std::cout << "int in use" << std::endl;
}   

template<>
void func( const double&)
{   
    std::cout << "double in use" << std::endl;
}   

int main()
{   
    func(3.4); // calls double
    func<int>(3.4); //calls int
}
```

Comment: The question was about **function** templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The example with manually given arguments is exactly with function template! And using it for class or function templates is the same here... doesn't matter! Have fun:-)